# ASP.NET Wizard get Value of Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, viewstate, wizard

I have an asp:Wizard in my Webforms application:

```
<WizardSteps>
    <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" StepType="Start" Title="a">  
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Enabled="True"></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:WizardStep>
    <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" runat="server" StepType="Complete" Title="b">  
    </asp:WizardStep>
</WizardSteps>
```

Now i want to access in the next step a value the user has entered in the TextBox1. In

```
Wizard1_NextButtonClick
```

i have access to the TextBox1.text, but the value the user entered is not in the text property. There is still the initial value? How can i access the value the user has entered? Viewstate of Wizard and Wizardsteps are enabled.

---

**solution:**
My fault was, that i set the TextBox1.Text on every Page_Load again to initial value. I didn't know that this event is fired by the Wizard next button.

So simple solution was to add an if case which asks for the PostBack state of the page

Comment: Are you enabling the textbox in some event (since i can see Enabled="False")? Because as long as it is disabled how the user can change the value? I tried the code and i am able to get the modified text from 'TextBox1.Text' in the 'Wizard1.NextButtonClick' event handler.

Comment: sorry, i pasted wrong code. I changed it to enabled. This is not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved the problem by myself. My fault was, that i set the TextBox1.Text on every Page_Load again to initial value. I didn't know that this event is fired by the Wizard next button.

So simple solution was to add an if case which asks for the PostBack state of the page:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
TextBox1.Text = Initialvalue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [this MSDN forum posting](http://forums.asp.net/t/1783159.aspx/1). Hope this will help you.

Comment: no, problem is not accessing the textbox1.text but that i have the inital value insted of the current the user has entered